# CSS Positioning Puzzle

Tags: html, css, xhtml

The image below represents a website layout I am trying to create.  The blue section (bottom right) represents an image should be behind the three neighboring elements and overflow them slightly.

I do not know the best way to do this, at the minute I have a wrapper div round the colored sections and put a background image in there but I am not sure if this is the best approach as the wrapper div needs to have a fixed size.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

http://www.gumpshen.com/images/layout.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be what you need...

**Your CSS should look something like this:**

```
    <!-- add CSS Reset before this -->

#header {
    background-color:#888;
    height:100px;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

#topleft {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index:3;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    min-height:100px;               
}

#topright {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:3;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    min-height:100px;               
}

#bottomleft {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:green;
    z-index:3;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    min-height:100px;               
}

#bottomright {
    position:absolute;
    left:49%;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
    padding:20px 0 0 17px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:2;
    min-height:100px;               
}
```

**Your HTML should look something like this:**

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="topleft">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div id="topright">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div id="bottomleft">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div id="bottomright">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
</div>
```

**note:** "lorem ipsum", opacity and min-height added just for show :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly this is my answer:

If the grey is a header, just treat it how you wish.

Then have a "content" div that wraps yellow, red, green and blue, which should be *relatively* positioned. From there you can *absolutely* position the blue so that it overlaps yellow, red and green. Then with some z-indexing you should have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Is it fixed width? If so, you can do some cheats with background images. If it's fixed with *and* fixed height, then even better - just save the whole image as a background.

You could also give your image a background image, like so:

```
#MyImage {
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  background: url(images/image-background.jpg) top left no-repeat;
}
```

The image will then sit in the middle, with the background showing around the edge. Then your image can be, say, 200x100px, with your background image being 220x120px.

Comment: This is what I have at the minute but it means the conatiner height must be set. I was wonderign if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you have the colored blocks figured out already.

Now you can put the original image in the blue box as a background, positioned at the right bottom and position a semi-transparent version of that image (or use css transparency) absolutely at the right bottom of your wrapper. The semi-transparent image on top of the original won´t show, it will just show in the surrounding boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative positioning to position the elements and don't forget to set the right Z-Index values to the div you want to put on top.